# How to pass data from state in redux to a react hook state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

In my react/redux app, i have data already in the state found in redux and i want to pass that data to my react **useState** in order to serve the component with the data in terms of getting the current state data or updating the state data.

I have tried but my way is not working. What is the most efficient way of going about solving this issue with react hook. Also how to configure the react **useEffect** properly.

```
// action
import { HrEmployeeData } from "../../actions/employeeHR";

const EmployeeTable = ({ employeesDetail, HrEmployeeData }) => {

  const [employeesDetail, setEmployeesDetail] = React.useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    HrEmployeeData();
  }, []);

  const classes = useStyles();

  const columns = [
    { name: "name", label: "Name" },
    { name: "phone_no", label: "Contact" },
    { name: "email", label: "Email" },
    { name: "department", label: "Department" },
    { name: "job_title", label: "Title" },
    { name: "salary", label: "Salary" },
    { name: "date_employed", label: "Date Employed" },
    {
      name: "Action",
      options: {
        filter: true,
        sort: false,
        empty: true,
        customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => {
          return (
            <button
              onClick={() =>
                window.alert(`Clicked "Edit" for row ${tableMeta.rowIndex}`)
              }
            >
              Edit
            </button>
          );
        },
      },
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>
            <MUIDataTable
              title={"Employees Records"}
              data={employeesDetail} <--- WHERE THE DATA IS BEEING USED
              columns={columns}
              options={options}
            />
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};

EmployeeTable.propTypes = {
  employeesDetail: PropTypes.object,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  employeesDetail: state.employeeHR.employeesDetail,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { HrEmployeeData })(EmployeeTable);
```

Comment: I believe employeesDetail is already passed as props from redux to your component, why do you need to use useState?

Comment: If you have the data in redux store, why do you want to save it in component's state? You could just subscribe to the redux store, which you are, and get the required data in your component. BTW `employeesDetail` is passed to your component as a prop.

Comment: If say i want to update a record, i figured if i used a state, then it would be easier to update by using **setEmployeesDetail({updatedData})**

Comment: You could just dispatch an action to update the data. When redux store is updated, your component will re-render with updated `employeesDetail` data.

Comment: So whenever i want to update the data i can use e.g a submit **button** then have its **onClick=action** where the action in my case is HrEmployeeData(). I'm i right?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to pass the data from the redux store the state.
The mechanism to use the redux store in components is "props".
In this case you're already mapping store to props and you can use it in the components.
Just remove the useState line.